# Export an entire database data ( db2 ) to csv file

Tags: sql, csv, db2

I have been looking for a command to export **an entire database** data (db2) to csv.

I did google it but it came up with db2 export command which only export table by table.

For example

```
export to employee.csv of del select * from employee
```

Therefore I have to do it for all the table and it can be very annoying. Is there a way I can export an entire database in db2 to csv? (or some other format that I can use with other databases)

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You could read the SYSIBM.SYSTABLES table to get the names of all the tables, and generate an export command for each table.

Write the export commands to an SQL file.

Read the SQL file, and execute the export commands.

Edited to add:  Warning - some of your foreign keys may not be synchronized, as the data base can be changed while you're reading the various tables.

Comment: I thought about that, but I would like something out of the box rather than go and create my own, I could do it though, even in bash.
And plus I would like to filter it based on the schema that they belong e.g. Database X has schemas Y and Z, I want only Y's tables

Comment: You have to decide which DB2 schemas you're interested in and you have to create the * .csv file names.  You might as well do it yourself.  You include the schemas you're interested in in the WHERE clause of the SYSIBM.SYSTABLES SELECT.

Answer (score 1):

```
# loop trough all the db2 db tables in bash and export them
# all this is just another oneliner ... 
# note the filter by schema name ... 
db2 -x "select schemaname from syscat.schemata where 1=1 and schemaname like 'GOSALES%'" | { while read -r schema ; do db2 connect to GS_DB ; db2 -x "SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM SYSIBM.TABLES WHERE 1=1 AND TABLE_CATALOG='GS_DB' AND TABLE_SCHEMA = '$schema'" | { while read -r table ; do db2 connect to GS_DB; echo -e "start table: $table \n" ; db2 -td@ "EXPORT TO $schema.$table.csv of del modified by coldel; SELECT * FROM $schema.$table " ; echo -e " stop table: $table " ; done ; } ; done ; }


 wc -l *.csv | sort -nr
 4185939 total
 446023 GOSALES.ORDER_DETAILS.csv
 446023 GOSALESDW.SLS_SALES_ORDER_DIM.csv
```